# How do I code a Shiny app in R that will update as new data is added to to google sheet I have it linked to?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working on creating a `Shiny` application in R. All the graphs displayed in this application are linked to a single Google Sheets page using googlesheets4. The Google Sheets page is linked to a Google Form where new survey responses will come in daily. I want the `Shiny` app to update and display graphs with the new survey information as it comes in. It doesn't matter if it updates on a set schedule or if it updates only when someone refreshes the application as long as it updates. But right now I can't get it to update at all without my program breaking down.

Below is the code I've already tried. My intent was for the program to check the Google sheet for new responses every 5 seconds or so and then update the graphs accordingly (first code chunk). However, I get this error:

[no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "c('reactiveExpr', 'reactive', 'function')"]

I think this is because later on (second code chunk) I'm filtering the data by a user input (users of the application can select a custom date range for the graph to filter by). Is there a way that I can fix my code so that it will update as new responses come in, but will also still be filterable so that my graphs are interactive?

```
# Load in data and set it up for automatic refreshing
rpe_data <- reactive({
                invalidateLater(5000)
                test_data <- googlesheets4::read_sheet("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n8VCCGRMj6AMM8u0prdwnQOh6jeHMoPUCh8lc-X-aj0/edit#gid=0")
                test_data %>% mutate(timestamp = format(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d"))
                 })
```

But then when I try to filter the data later on in the server for my interactive graphs the code doesn't work:

```
    # Render the average rating plot
    output$mean_rpe <- renderPlot({
      
      mean_data <- aggregate(rating ~ timestamp, rpe_data, mean)
        
      startDate <- input$range[1]
      endDate <- input$range[2]
      
      final_data <- mean_data %>%
        filter(timestamp >= startDate & timestamp <= endDate)
      
      ggplot(final_data, aes(x = timestamp, y = rating, group = 1)) + 
        geom_line(color = "#1fede6", size = 1.2) +
        geom_point(color = "#e82c1e", size = 3) +
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 10), n.breaks = 12) +
        labs(x = "Date", y = "Average RPE Rating", title = "Average NCRC RPE Ratings by Date") +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20))
    })
```

Comment: `rpe_data` is a reactive (a special type of function).  `rpe_data()` is the *current value* of `rpe_data`.  So you need to reference `rpe_data()` in your `renderPlot()`, not `rep_data`.

Comment: Also, I stongly urge against using limits in a scale function to set the axis limits. `coord_cartesian()` is vastly preferable, IMHO. The reason is that `coord_cartesian()` uses the full data set to construct the plot and then "zooms" to the required area. A scale function with limits first filters the data set and then plots the graph. That's not an issue here, but if any interpolation, model fitting, or calculation of summary statistics is involved in the construction of the graph, it can lead to errors that are difficult to detect. Best avoid bad habits at all times!